# What does the Deduction skill do?

Tags: another-case-solved

It states in the skill tree "One more move to collect a candy on puzzles". The way i understand this seems to make this skill a PitA. It would take 1 more moves to get a candy?

Comment: Is there a limit to how many moves you can take?  If so, this probably increases that limit by 1, rather than increasing the difficulty.

Comment: If that is so, not yet there but soon will, it's pretty useless for such a high skill. Cause most cases give you between 30 and 40 moves to complete... +1 would be pretty useless, thanks for trying at least!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the skill after much progress in the game and i now understand what it does.

It allows you to see in advance what is the secret candy's requirement. So having it level 1 is really helpful if the requirement is based on a number of evidence. When it is based off clues, it was already pretty simple.

Getting more than a level is IMO useless unless you have finished the game and have nothing left to spend on as 2 moves is more than enough to get practically any evidence...